# Error in Google Web app in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-launcher

I just created my first application for Google App Engines. I have saved .py and .yml file in a folder in the C drive. I have installed python 2.5 as well as Google app launcher where i have set the python path as 'C:\Python25\pythonw.exe'. When I open the launcher, click on add existing application and select the particular folder containing the .py and .yml files, and run the application, i get the following error -
"Cannot run project. Please confirm these values in your  Preferences, or take an appropriate measure to fix it(eg install Python)"

I have installed python 2.7.3 but it din't work for that either. I will be grateful if anyone helps me out, I am newbie to the programming world.

Comment: Which values is it asking you to confirm? Have you included an app id in the `app.yaml` file?

Comment: I have included app id in yml file(simpleinterest101).The complete error message is like this --"App Engine program C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\pyglib\dev_appserver.py not found.

Cannot run project C:\simpleinterest 101. Please confirm these values in your Preference, or take an appropriate measure to fix it(eg install Python)"

Comment: Did you check if the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\pyglib\dev_appserver.py` exists? Did you specify the full path to your project directory? Right now, the SDK thinks your project is at `C:\simpleinterest 101`.

Comment: There is no dev_appserver.py file in  the pyglib folder. My project is at `c:\simpleinterest101`. In Preferences, i have entered the following details :: Python path: `C:\Python25\pythonw.exe` . App Engine SDK :: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\pyglib`. I have kept the editor and deployment field blank.  Which path should be selected in the App Engine SDK path ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment